# Click is not working in selenium

Tags: vb.net, automation, selenium, mstest

```
        selenium.Click("Search")
        selenium.Click("Display")
        selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000")
        Assert.IsTrue(selenium.GetTitle() = "Display")
        selenium.ChooseOkOnNextConfirmation()
```

''Tried all the following possible solutions to click a button but all failed to do so. Page timeout after some time.

```
        selenium.FireEvent("Cancel", "click")
        'selenium.FireEvent("Cancel", "keypress")
        'selenium.Submit("Cancel")
        'selenium.FireEvent("Cancel", "click")
        'selenium.MouseDownAt("Cancel", "Click")
        'selenium.MouseUpAt("Cancel", "Click")
        'selenium.MouseDown("Cancel")
        'selenium.KeyPress("Cancel", "Click")
        'selenium.FireEvent("id=Cancel", "Click")
        'selenium.Click("Cancel")
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(7000)
        Assert.IsTrue(Regex.IsMatch(selenium.GetConfirmation(), "Are you sure you want to cancel?"))
```

There is a confirm dialog box on clicking the cancel button. But selenium is not clicking it at all. Any idea how to do this.

Desperate for an early reply..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is Selenium latching onto the object? Try providing a different Locator (XPath, CSS, etc.) for your button.
For instance, change `selenium.click("Search");` to `selenium.click("css=button.button[id=Search]");`